# Google search C# через прокси

Tags: c#, proxy, google-search

Нужно сделать в приложении поиск через google. Нашел хорошую библиотеку [google-api-for-dotnet](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/). Поиск осуществляется просто:

```cs
GwebSearchClient client = new GwebSearchClient("");

IList<IWebResult> results = client.Search("война и мир", 10);
foreach (IWebResult result in results) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", result.Url);
}
```

Но так как программа будет делать очень много запросов, хотелось бы защититься (общаться через прокси сервера). Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Это вам надо в документацию вашего `GwebSearchClient` смотреть.

Comment: В API ничего полезного не оказалось. Как вариант - задание глобального прокси WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy(адрес_прокси_сервера); Но столкнулся с ещё одной проблемой: очень сложно найти нормально работающий бесплатный прокси сервер. Вопрос можно закрыть.

Comment: @Василий12345678 дело в том, что это форум = книга знаний, поэтому вопросы закрывают только если он не соответствует правилам форума.